# Git merge gives conflicts for almost all files changed from only one branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, merge, conflict

I tried to merge my local branch with our development branch, but `git merge` gave me conflict for almost all files that were changed in local branch. So I had to resolve conflicts manually. Most of those files were not changed in development.

For example, I get this conflict:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
        render json: {:created => 'true'}.to_json, status: :created, location: @user
=======
        render json: {:created => 'true'}.to_json, status: :created, location: @user
>>>>>>> development
```

Or this one:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
        # some new code
=======
>>>>>>> development
```

Notice that I have no new line in one of the branches.

Someone knows why this happens, and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to some local files has changed and not committed before you pull/checkout from the git repository.

Remove these extra lines from the conflicted files and commit then.

Comment: I have no files that has changed and not committed. I have made a commit for all my files. What else can it be?

Answer (score 0):

What about line ending? This could be an issue, especially when your devs / you are working on different operating systems.

https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

Comment: i agree that line endings are often a problem. i disagree with githubs suggestion to set autocrlf to anything other than false.

Comment: Thanks @nTraum. But I am working on the same operating system as dev,so I don't think 'line ending' is my issue.